# Find and display rows with approximately close entries

Tags: python, csv

I'm writing a code to find not duplicates but rather, approximately close values in a csv file.
I want to be able to find all values that are in the same row that have a difference of no more than 1.0
The csv file looks like this:

```
Time    Chan1   Chan2
04:07.0 52.31515503 16.49450684
04:07.1 23.55230713 62.48802185
04:08.0 46.06217957 24.94955444
04:08.0 41.72077942 31.32516479
04:08.0 19.80723572 25.73182678
```

I want to find values of Chan1 and Chan 2 that are within 1.0 of each other.
This is all I have:

```
import nump as np
from matplotlib import *
from pylab import *
filename = raw_input("Enter file name: ")+'.csv'
filepath = 'home/home/david/Desktop/'+filename
col1=[row[2] for row in data]
col2=[row[3] for row in data]
```

But I dont know where to go from here, I dont know if I should use an 'if' state or if there's any other way to get the information I need. I ultimately, want the program to print 3 things:

The row in which very close (close by <=1.0) values in Chan1 and Chan2 are found, Chan1, and Chan2.

Here are edits I just made:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import *
from pylab import *


filename = raw_input("Enter file name: ") + '.csv'
filepath = '/home/david/Desktop/' + filename


data = np.genfromtxt(filepath, delimiter=',', dtype=float)




first=[row[0] for row in data]
rownum1=[row[1] for row in data]
rownum2=[row[2] for row in data]

#if (abs(rownum1-rownum2)<=1):
#       print( first, rownum1, rownum2)

count=0
for row in data:
     count++
     if (abs(row[1]-row[2]) <= 1.0):
            print('The values in row 0 are 1 and 2, are within 1.0 of each other.', format(count, row[1], row[2])
```

Comment: What error are you getting? I assume it has something to do with numpy and trying to iterate over a numpy array, but basically you need to iterate through the 'rows', compare the two relevant values, and print the result if applicable. I can't recall how to wrangle numpy stuff, so if that is where the issue lies, you will need to consult their documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can solve your problem using standard library function.

Just friendly note :

these 3 lines

```
first=[row[0] for row in data]
rownum1=[row[1] for row in data]
rownum2=[row[2] for row in data]
```

will do 3 x 10.000 loop, you better do splitting while you read data per line.

And please copy paste the error as per @0O0O0O0 request

```
try:
    text_file = open("list_number.txt", "r") #File contain your 5 line data, with header removed

    try:
        count = 0
        for row in text_file:
            col = row.split() # switch to row.split(',') if you're using coma delimiter
            count+=1
            if abs(float(col[1]) - float(col[2])) <= 10: # Change to 1
                #print('The values in row %s are %s and %s, are within 10.0 of each other.' % (count, col[1], col[2]))
                print('The values in row {0} are {1} and {2}, are within 10.0 of each other.'.format(count, col[1], col[2]))
    finally:        
        text_file.close()

except IOError as e:
    print("Unable to open file : ", e)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can determine if the two values are within 1.0 of each other using subtraction and the absolute value function:

```
count = 0
for row in data:
    count++
    if (abs(row[2] - row[3]) <= 1.0):
        print('The values in row {0} are {1} and {2}, and are within 1.0 of each other.'.format(count, row[2], row[3]))
```

Comment: I get a 'list' error. How would I fix that? It's a huge 10,000 row csv file.

Comment: I am not sure. I edited my answer so that it could address all three questions you posed - does it work now? If not, what is the error you are getting?